# Select2 Issue copying option selected to a disabled field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to copy the selected value from a select2 component to another one which is disabled. I was able to transfer the value from both hidden selects (select2 actually hides the regular selects and creates a new html structure) but I am not able to copy the text to the span. 
I have a jsfiddle that exemplifies my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vktyaLmp/.

Is this the right approach to copying values from a select2 component to another one? 
Is there a built-in method?

This is my code:

```
$("#originSelect, #targetSelect").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 1
});

if ($('#originSelect').val() != 0) {
   $('#select2-chosen-2').text(   $('#originSelect').val()   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 gives you built in function to get/set values directly. You can replace your javascript with the following code :

```
$("#originSelect, #targetSelect").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 1
});

$("#originSelect").change(function(e) {
    if ($('#originSelect').val() != 0) {
        $('#targetSelect').select2('val', $('#originSelect').select2('val'));
    }
});
```

(I just tested it in your Fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You're not capturing the change event of the original Select you need to do it like this

```
    $('#originSelect').change(function(){


   $('#targetSelect').select2('val', $('#originSelect').select2("val").toString());

   });
```